App is successfully uploaded to Appstore connect but yet still asking for 6 digit code
I am making an auto deployment to Apple Appstore using Azure Devops Pipeline.
I had successfully deploy the App to Appstore Connect but it still asking for 6 digit code.
Successfully uploaded to AppStore but asking for 6 digit code
Heres my pipeline code
- task: AppStoreRelease@1
  inputs:
    serviceEndpoint: 'Apps Store Connection'
    releaseTrack: 'TestFlight'
    appIdentifier: 'com.company.myapp'
    appType: 'iOS'
    ipaPath: 'output/package/some.ipa'
    appSpecificId: '1234567'

In my Service Connection, I had input my App-specific Password and Fast-lane Session and I am using Basic Authentication.

Based on the error message, it seems that the 2FA (Two-Factor Authentication) related environment variables are not set on the agent machine. See "Environment variables to set".
You can try to set the related environment variables on the agent machine like as below:

Set the following variables in the pipeline.


Set the secret variables.


Set the general variables.




In the YAML pipeline, before the AppStoreRelease@1 task, you need to map the secret variables as environment variables. The general variables are automatically mapped to environment variables. See below example.
jobs:
- job: publish
  . . .
  steps:
  . . .

  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'Set environment variabes'
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=FASTLANE_SESSION]$(fastlane_session)"
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD]$(app_specific_password)"

  - task: AppStoreRelease@1
    inputs:
      serviceEndpoint: 'Apps Store Connection'
      releaseTrack: TestFlight
      appIdentifier: 'com.company.myapp'
      appType: iOS
      ipaPath: 'output/package/some.ipa'
      appSpecificId: '1234567'





Thanks, not sure if it works or not, need to try on next version. Is there a way to test it? If i run it now i will face version number crashed with the current one.

@MensinBM, Do you have other Apple account that also has 2FA enabled? Maybe, you can use it to test.
